# "white-space: pre;" CSS style does not seem to work according to W3C spec in <textarea> HTML element - it always wraps, not just on newlines

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wish to make a **textarea** HTML element wrap lines only on newlines without collapsing leading whitespace.

The W3C spec says the CSS style element **white-space: pre;** should give me the behavior I want, but it does not work - it does not collapse leading whitespace, but it always wraps, not just on newlines.

**white-space: nowrap;** does not wrap except on newlines like I want, but unfortunately it collapses leading whitespace.

The only thing that works the way I need it to is the **wrap="off"** HTML attribute, but that is not supported in the W3C spec.  It works perfectly though, and seems to work in all browsers I have tried.  It bothers me it is unsupported by the spec though.

Can anyone tell me why this seems to be the case and give a means of doing this that is supported by W3C?  Maybe it is something else I am overlooking like a default for some other style element or something?  Maybe there is a way using JavaScript?

The pertinent section in the W3C spec is found [HERE](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop).

Here is some code that shows the problem:

```html
<textarea style="white-space: pre; width: 400px">          This line will wrap but the spec seems to indicate it should not.  SHOULD work?</textarea><br>
<textarea style="white-space: nowrap; width: 400px">          I could do this but it collapses leading whitespace unfortunately</textarea>
<textarea wrap="off" style="width: 400px;">          This works but is not part of the standard.  It should be unsupported.  It is the only thing that does what I want.</textarea>
```

Comment: CSS can't control the layout of `<textarea>` contents.

Comment: @Pointy It seems to be able to - nowrap collapses leading white space, for instance, in the sample code I show.  It also does not wrap on newlines, but pre does, and other CSS style elements have other effects on the visual layout of the contents.

Comment: Well it can affect *some* things: padding, font, color, background, border, etc.

Comment: @Pointy It can affect both collapse/non-collapse of white space and wrapping, which is what this entire question is about :) It just does not seem to do it per the spec int he browsers I have tried

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `textarea` element has always had special implementations with variation across browsers. The original idea in HTML 2.0 was that the user can enter arbitrarily long lines, with horizontal scrollbars provided by the browser as needed, and only line break actually entered by the user would produce new lines. Implementations introduced both “soft” and “hard” wrapping, however, and gradually made “soft” wrapping (lines are wrapped visually but not internally – submitted data still has only user-entered line breaks) the default. The attribute `wrap=hard` was introduced as a nonstandard way of getting “hard” wrapping (wrapping also adds actual line breaks to the element’s value), and for quite some time, the nonstandard attribute `wrap=off` was the only way to achieve the behavior that was then standard!

HTML 4 then partly retrofitted the specification to implementations; it [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#edef-TEXTAREA): “Users should be able to enter longer lines than [the value of the `cols` attribute], so user agents should provide some means to scroll through the contents of the control when the contents extend beyond the visible area. User agents may wrap visible text lines to keep long lines visible without the need for scrolling.” It does not define any way for authors to specify whether “soft” wrapping takes place (or to ask for “hard” wrapping).

In HTML5 drafts, as noted, there is the `wrap` attribute, but with only two conforming values `hard` and `soft`, and the latter really means “no hard wrapping” – the text may or may not visually wrap, and this is apparently left to be handled in CSS. There is some logic here, since the attribute is now for *functional* control only (whether wrapping causes line breaks to be added to the actual value).

But although `wrap=off` is declared nonconforming (forbidden, obsolete), the HTML5 drafts describe its effect. As noted here in comments, the description is in the “Rendering” section and as “suggested rendering” and as affecting via CSS. This means that the drafts do not require browsers to support `wrap=off`, just “expects” it, and only as part of the CSS cascade, i.e. only when CSS is enabled and there is no CSS rule that overrides it.

Thus, although `wrap=off` works well and there is little reason to expect it to stop working, it is not conforming and it is not “guaranteed” to work (i.e., HTML5 drafts do not impose a requirement on browsers).

The varying support to `white-space` for `textarea` in browsers makes it an unreliable tool here.

As a workaround, you might consider creating a simulation of `textarea` with an editable block, e.g. with

```
<div class=textarea contenteditable=true>...</div>
```

and CSS code like

```
.textarea { 
  font-family: Consolas, monospace;
  white-space: pre;
  word-wrap: normal;
  padding: 0.1em 0.3em;
  border: solid thin;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 25em; /* fallback for browsers not supporting ch */
  width: 60ch;
}
```

And if the data is to be submitted as part of form data, you would need to copy it to a hidden field before submission.

This would work reasonably (even old versions of IE support `contenteditable`), except that it is too powerful: browsers typically let users enter “rich text” in an editable element. Moreover, they tend to generate markup (tags) like `<br>` rather than newline chaacters when the user hits Enter, so your JavaScript code would need to do some cleanup to turn the content to plain text.

So the workaround isn’t particularly good, but it’s probably the best approach if you need to conform to HTML5 drafts and still get the functionality.

Comment: This is a lot to chew on.  I will look over the specs to see how your history fits in with those and experiment with some of your ideas.  Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Great answer, Jukka.

Answer (score 2):

To quote the great and mighty [Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/textarea-tricks/):

> To prevent text from wrapping normally in CSS, you use #whatever { white-space: nowrap; }. But for whatever reason, that doesn't work with textareas. If you want to be able to type into textareas and would rather lines do not break until you press return/enter (a horizontal scrollbar is triggered instead), you'll have to use the wrap="off" attribute.

```
<textarea wrap=off ...>
  Hello world
</textarea>
```

Comment: wrap="off" is unsupported per W3C, I believe.  style="white-space: pre;" should do the trick per W3C spec, but does not for whatever reason.  Do you know if there is any way to do it that works per spec, or am I interpreting the spec incorrectly?  Or is this just a quirk I will have to live with?

Comment: @aeoril Well strictly speaking the W3C doesn't support *anything*; there's no W3C-issued browser. But the "wrap" attribute is [definitely in the HTML5 spec.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-textarea-wrap)

Comment: wrap yes, wrap="off" no - only wrap="soft" or wrap="hard" - I tried both, neither one gives the desired behavior

Comment: @aeoril [I disagree](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/N7rq6/) - the "wrap" attribute seems to disable auto-wrapping of typed text. In your own question in fact you say it works "perfectly"! *edit* Oh I see what you mean - the "off" value is not in the spec. Well given that it's apparently supported by all current (major?) browsers, I suspect it's just a matter of time.

Comment: @Pointy - more relevantly the [HTML5 spec rendering section for textarea says](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/rendering.html#the-textarea-element-0) "User agents are expected to apply the 'white-space' CSS property to textarea elements. For historical reasons, if the element has a wrap attribute whose value is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the string "off", then the user agent is expected to treat the attribute as a presentational hint setting the element's 'white-space' property to 'pre'." But `white-space:pre` does not seem to be implemented yet for some reason.

Comment: @Alohci You seem to have hit on my answer - thanks.  I think it is safe to use the wrap="off" now until style="white-space: pre;" is properly implemented widely.  Can you make this into an answer and I will mark it as "answered" for other people to benefit? Thanks again! :)

Comment: @aeoril you can always do both - since `wrap=off` is officially meaningless, maybe when the `white-space` property is properly obeyed then `wrap=off` will just do nothing, and your CSS will take over.

Comment: @Pointy I will give that a shot - I think I tried that and it worked ok, so that is a good idea actually to cover the code long term.  Thanks.

Comment: @Pointy Please note in your code snippet in this answer you left out the quotes around "off", might confuse some people

Comment: @aeoril quotes are not required in HTML5 :)

Comment: Well as per spec the `wrap` attribute is not meant to influence how the textarea content is _displayed_ at all – it’s only supposed to specify how the _submitted_ data is to be treated (line breaks inserted _according_ to how it was displayed or not). If `wrap=off` works as you want it to (make sure to test that cross-browser, because even in your fiddle I’m seeing different results in Chrome, Firefox and Opera[12]) – then use it.

Comment: [contd.] “Validity” should never be an end in itself – or as it was put in one of Pratchett’s novels, _“Look, that’s why there’s rules, understand? So that you __think__ before you break ’em.”_ ;-)

Comment: @CBroe Is this like a "hippy anarchist" thing? :) lol and thanks, Pointy, I did not know that

Comment: @aeoril they're required when it'd be a syntax issue (like, spaces in the attribute value), but not otherwise

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the spaces extra spaces with a non breaking space.

```
<textarea style="white-space: nowrap; width: 400px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Leading space will still be there and the line will not wrap.</textarea>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bZR6/)

Now to get IE to play along, overflow:scroll needs to be added to force the scrollbars

```
<textarea style="white-space: nowrap; width: 400px; overflow-x:scroll">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Leading space will still be there and the line will not wrap.</textarea>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bZR6/1/)

And the kicker, **Firefox does not support** whitespace on a textarea, so until they fix  [bug: 82711](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=82711), you need to use the nowrap attribute.

Comment: That won't help once the user starts typing, will it?

Comment: @Pointy You are saying the user can not enter in multiple whitespace? Yes they can....

Comment: It would be difficult to implement for a user input textarea, per @Pointy

Comment: How is it difficult? On the server you need to convert over the spaces. Since `nowrap` will collapse by its definition, this is the only option you have.

Comment: @epascarello yes, but they can't enter `&nbsp;` :)

Comment: @epascarello yes typed spaces indent leading text in a `<textarea>`. I think the focus of the question is the `white-space` CSS property.

Comment: Which is what I answered, if you do not want it to collapse, you need to use the `&nbsp;` A user typing into it will be able to add multiple white spaces, the developer would need to do the conversion if they plan on redisplaying it. If you do not do it, that you need to use the attribute the OP was trying to avoid using.

Comment: In Firefox and Chrome, the text in the jsfiddle wraps. In IE it does not (and there is no horizontal scrollbar in the area). So this hardly counts as an answer to the problem.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela IE is fixed with adding overflow to it and FF does not support whitespace.